# Design - Breadcrumbs Javascript

Tags: javascript, breadcrumbs

Recently we've received a design that uses breadcrumbs, but specifies a breadcrumb for a page that does not exist. In effect, the breadcrumb in question, relates to a section of a top-level page.  We're wondering if this use of breadcrumbs is not advisable or whether this is more common than we're aware of.

Example:
Page 1 (main information page, contains 2-4 sections describing topics contained in sub-pages. each topic's text is marked up using html using a H1 or H2).
Page 2 (is a page that list products related to the topics on page 1).

The design is this:
**Page 1 >** 
This is our top-level page. The user is presented with 3-4 sets of products grouped by hyperlinked Topic text (as HTML H1's or H2's).

When the user clicks on a Topic they are taken to Page 2:
The breadcrumb this new design specifies is this:
**Page 1 > Topic Text > Page 2**

And when a user clicks the Topic Text "breadcrumb", they are taken to Page 1, and CSS is used to highlight the H1 or H2 Topic Text the user originally clicked on.

The above seems odd in that the "Topic text" breadcrumb does not relate to a page. Are we being too purist in our interpretation of the use of breadcrumbs?

Also, suggestions for how to best to implement this would be welcome.  We'll need to pass some value or indicator from the second level page back to the first when the user selected the "Topic text" breadcrumb. JavaScript?  queryString?

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: This question should be asked at [UX.SE], with the implementation paragraph removed. If you want to ask about implementation, you're right at StackOverflow (except you want a library/[softwarerecs.SE]); but we would need a more detailed description of your problem (best with code).

Comment: Thanks. I've re-asked this question at: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/65182/breadcrumbs-is-this-a-valid-use.